# Filter nested collection not working as expected with Querydsl, Spring Data REST

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, querydsl

Based on [StoreRepository](https://gist.github.com/olivergierke/decf03d4948cd58a51bc) by @[Oliver Gierke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18122/oliver-gierke)

If `Store` has a collection of `products`

`/api/store?products.name=Sony%20Vaio`

Returns Stores that has Sony Viao on it's products Good, But all products returned,
I need Only product with name Sony Viao.

```
public interface StoreRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Store, String>, 
    QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Store>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QStore> {

    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QStore store) {
        bindings.bind(store.products.any().first((path, value) -> path.equals(value));
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you really need to customize the QueryDSL bindings as you are trying to? Your code works for me without the `customize` method. Sample project available [on Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/43947202) to review.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you don't specify the property name inside product. Try this:

```
bindings.bind(store.products.any().name).first((path, value) -> path.eq(value));
```